# What is the topology on $G=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb Z/(p^n)$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be any prime number and $G=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb Z/(p^n)$ be the direct product of the finite cyclic groups $\mathbb Z/(p^n)$. Let $H=\mathbb Z_p$ be the group of $p$-adic integers with its usual norm $|.|_p$. Then the function $f_n:G\to H$ sending a sequence $(x_k)_{k=1}^{\infty} \in G$ to its $n$-th term $x_n \in \{0, 1, \dots , p^n − 1\} \subset \mathbb Z_p$ is a **continuous** $p^{−n}$–homomorphism.

As there is a term "continuity" of the map $f_n:G\to H$, there should be topologies on both $G$ and $H$, with respect to which $f_n$ is continuous.

Here, I've two questions.

**Question 1 :** It seems that the topology on $H=\mathbb Z_p$ is generated by the metric induced by the norm $|.|_p$. Is it true?

**Question 2 :** What is the topology on $G=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb Z/(p^n)$?

Comment: A1: Yes. A2: Most likely the product topology of discrete topologies on the factors. I don't know of other "natural" topologies for that space.

Comment: I agree. If you construct the $p$-adic integers more algebraically (not via completions and metrics, but via inverse limits) one will also take $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ as a discrete space, take the product over $n \geq 1$ and realize the $p$-adic integers as a subspace (which is just the concrete construction of the inverse limit in the category of groups).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen What is happened if we take other topology instead of discrete topology on the factors of $G$?

Comment: Connection with adeles and ideles (https://mathoverflow.net/q/41253/88984) ?

Comment: There is no homomorphism $\Bbb{Z}/(p^n) \to \Bbb{Z}_p$ except the one sending everything to $0$.

Comment: You haven't answered whether the reference I gave on mathoverflow was pertinent or not ...

Comment: Isn't it more ot less the same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3327951?

Comment: Concerning question 1 see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number#Topology.